# EXTRACT the search data in the WORD TABLE to EXCEL using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How can I extract the search data in the word table using macros.

***SAMPLE TABLE:***

```
Name     Age     Sex     Address     Number
Adam     18      Male    Manila       1
Rina     18     Female   Manila       2
```

I want to get the Number when I search Rina.

Can anyone help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrOut As String
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = InputBox("What is the Name to Find")
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
    MsgBox "The Number is: " & Split(.Rows(1).Cells(5).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very basic question and if you search on google you will find lots of answer. However you can do it in variety of way. Use `VLookup()` like below.

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,A2:E3,5)
```

You can use `Index()/Match()` combination like-

```
=INDEX(E2:E3,MATCH(G2,A2:A3,0))
```

If you have <kbd>Office365</kbd> then can use `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(G2,A2:A3,E2:E3)
```

[image]

Comment: what if the table I'm accessing is in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Then please search on google first then post your effort. Also tag the question `ms-word`.

Comment: @Harun24HR Your 'answer' ignores the first sentence in the OP's post, which clearly say «search data in the word table». The Excel functions you posted are *not available* in Word.

Comment: @macropod It would better if OP mention `MS-Word` table.

Comment: @Harun24HR They clearly referred to a «word table». You just didn't pay attention...

Comment: @macropod OP added `MS-Word` tag after my comment. See edit history please.

Comment: The OP said «search data in the word table» *before* editing the tag. Check the edit history for yourself!